# Exception on azure script insert if no record exists else update script

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

my Insert Script:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
item.userId= user.userId;


var table = tables.getTable('mytabble');
table.where({ 
   name: item.name
}).read({
   success: upsertItem
});

function upsertItem(existingItems) {
    if (existingItems.length === 0) {
        request.execute();
    } else {
    item.id = existingItems[0].id;
      table.update(item, {
        success: function(updatedItem) {
            request.respond(200, updatedItem)
        }
      });
    }
 }
```

}

mytable:

```
public class myTabble
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "age")]
    public int age { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fname")]
    public string fname { get; set; }
 }
```

my Insert Function:

```
private async void InsertTodoItem(myTabble todoItem)
    {


            await todoTable.InsertAsync(todoItem);
            items.Add(todoItem);



    }
```

The update button function

```
private void Save_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var name1 = name.Text;
                var age1 = Convert.ToInt32(age.Text);
                var fname1 = fname.Text;

                var todoItem = new myTabble { name = name1, age = age1, fname = fname1 };
                InsertTodoItem(todoItem);
                //NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid input");
            }

        }
```

When I am trying to insert info for previously existing name It is updated properly but at the same time i am getting an exception at my insert function.

Comment: It could be your items.Add() call, since if this is an update the item may already be in items.  Can you try commenting that out and seeing if you get an exception?  If so, can you post the exception you are getting?

Comment: This is the same issue as you're describing at http://stackoverflow.com/q/21098510/751090; please edit your original question to add the details of the problems you're having, instead of creating another one.

Comment: Thank you.. After commenting out items.add() it is working.

Comment: @carlosfigueira: Sorry I am new here so don't know the rules. from next time onwards I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the exception is coming from items.add(), you should verify the item is not already in the items collection.  Something like this should work for you:

```
if (items.IndexOf(item) == -1)
{
    items.Add(todoItem);  
}
```

Depending on what you are changing, you may need to remove and read add the item instead from the collection.